# Selecting A8 Paper

Tags: document-classes, geometry, paper-size, article, document-configuration

As I frequently use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
```

I though a simple change could select the A8 paper:

```
\documentclass[a8paper,12pt]{article}
```

But I get a warning saying the `a8paper` option is not used and the document size is still A4. I also tried `a8` as option, but no luck. How can I specify the document size to A8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to specify out-of-the-ordinary document sizes/dimensions. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=74mm,paperwidth=52mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
...
```

Alternatively, you could also specify A8-size paper using `papersize={<width>,<height>}` where `<width>=52mm` and `<height>=74mm`. There is no `a8paper` option for `geometry` (or for the `article` document class), hence the manual specification. A-paper dimensions are available from: http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm

Answer (score 9):

Use `\usepackage[paper=A8,pagesize=auto]{typearea}`